# how to fix localdate UTC issue in mongodb spring boot application for LocalDate field?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, utc, objectmapper, localdate

when receiving message from RabbitMQ, the json is parsed using a Object Mapper.

The parse is happening successfully, but mongodb stores the date in localate timestamp like

> "projectStartDate" : **ISODate("2020-11-01T00:00:00.000+05:30")**

which is fine but when I see this date in UTC, it is something like this

> "projectStartDate" : **ISODate("2020-10-31T18:30:00.000Z")**

Therefore, as UI shows date in UTC, it shows 2020-10-31 instead of 2020-11-01.

## ***`How to fix this?`***

(ProjectDTO.java) the field details is below:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM-d-yyyy")
private LocalDate projectStartDate;
```

parsing code is:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
ProjectDTO projectDTO = mapper.readValue(message, ProjectDTO.class);
```

Comment: MongoDB does not have a facility to store dates (it only stores timestamps) and it is not timezone-aware. I am unfamiliar with what tools spring boot provides for date to timestamp conversion, but the data will be converted to a timestamp in some fashion when it is stored.